# Is Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 available for power pc?

Tags: 14.04, unity, live-cd, powerpc

I have been looking to install Ubuntu on my Powerbook 1.67GHz with 1Gb of RAM.
I can easily find the 12.04 desktop live cd image but can only find 14.04 server, Lubuntu or Mate. Is it possible to get 14.04 or later as a "straight" Ubuntu live desktop image?

Comment: I presume it would crash if I tried a distribution upgrade too.

Answer (score 2):

yes. i think it does my friend.
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/

Comment: This just links to the server image for power pc without the desktop.

Comment: @SimonBaldwin You can also download the Desktop version from that page.

Comment: @KevinBowen what do you expect the answer to contain? The whole ubuntu binary image in answer?

Comment: The page linked to only contains server images for ppc architecture. The desktop image is only for AMD64 architecture.

Comment: I could install the server image and then install unity but I asked the question above because I looking for a live desktop image to test if it works on my device.

Comment: But your question is answered!  ;)  Just install it to a USB drive (and put the boot record on there too) and then [accept the answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks Fabby but I found my own answer, Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop does not support the ppc architecture. I will have to try Mate or Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found this:

[Ubuntu ditches powerpc builds](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/07/ubuntu-ditching-powerpc-builds)

So no Ubuntu Desktop after 13.04... Mate or Lubuntu from now on...